# I can't extract text from a given xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

My code was working normally for several days, but now it just stopped copying text from XPATH and I can't figure out why.
Can someone help me?

```
url = 'https://eventos.congresse.me/nutcon/edicoes/528-ii-nutcon---2-edicao/anais'
driver.get(url)
title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, /html/body/main/div/div/ul[1]/li[36]/a/h4).text
print(title)
```

I changed several times the way to copy the XPATH but all were in vain.
This piece of code is in one iteration. The code does not show an error, but the text is blank.

Comment: Ok, now I see you have edited the code and included `.text`. Code looks fine. What error do you get? Can you share the error in the question?

Comment: This piece of code is in one iteration. The code does not show an error, but the text is blank.

Comment: Check my updated answer about applying `waits`. Also, I see a typo error in your code above, quotes (single/or double) are missing in the XPATH expression of following line, hope this is just a typo error! `title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, /html/body/main/div/div/ul[1]/li[36]/a/h4).text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looping through all of the proceedings on the page and printing the titles and maybe other info from each. I think you have 2 problems:

1. Your locator is grabbing some headings that aren't visible.
2. You need to add a wait to make sure all the headings are loaded before you start looping.

I've updated your code with these changes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = "https://eventos.congresse.me/nutcon/edicoes/528-ii-nutcon---2-edicao/anais"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
proceedings = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.proceeding h4")))
print(len(proceedings))
for e in proceedings:
    print(e.text)
```

This prints

```
36
```

and then all the proceeding titles.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to wait for the desired element to be visible, try the below code, if not tried already:

```
title = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div/div/ul[1]/li[36]/a/h4"))).text
print(title)
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```